# Primeng multiselect need Select All checkbox with 'Select All' text

Tags: primeng

Primeng multi select need Select All checkbox with 'Select All' text. Sample code is include here:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [filter]="true" [showHeader]="true"  [showToggleAll]="true" formControlName="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: You can see answer in similar topic here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914546/how-to-add-the-text-all-next-to-select-all-check-box-in-primeng-multiselect/72258941#:~:text=You%20can%20add,absolute%3B%0A%20%20%20%20left%3A%2040px%3B%0A%7D